# How to fix the layout properly in android?

Tags: android

I am working on test application. I need to display the **questions and options**. The number of options for each question are not known before hand. i.e **for each question there are different number of options** and hence I am displaying the **options dynamically**.

**My Code:**

**list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<com.splash.Header
        android:id="@+id/layoutheader" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/listview" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/topbar"
  android:layout_width="330dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/topplain"
>
</ImageView> 

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/home"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/homebtn" 
 android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</ImageView> 

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/backbtn"
 android:layout_marginTop="4dip"    
 android:layout_marginLeft="255dip"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:onClick="back" 
>
</ImageView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listitem.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:id="@+id/lnrlayout"> 



     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" 
       android:layout_below="@+id/casedescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        ></TextView>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/rlt_main" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/chkboxes" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_question"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


   </LinearLayout>  


   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my problem is **based on the size of the question the layout is expanding otherwise the layout is displaying only upto half screen as shown in the picture.** How to solve this issue. I tried a lot to adjust the layout but still I am facing the same problem. Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: you better use relative layout instead of linear

Comment: hi for which one I should use relative layout..is that for listview?

Comment: when you want to show question option then pop up a custom dialog(that contain listview of option) when click on particular question

Comment: hi i used relative layout but still the same problem....Please help me regarding this

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
istead of this use
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

Answer (score 1):

check you gotta given some "layout_marginBottom" property somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

I guess Cut off your `ScrollView` Tag inside list item

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/lnrlayout"> 

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/lnrlayout1"> 

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlayout1"> 
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/checkboxes" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


   </LinearLayout>  
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi I removed the scrollview but even then I am facing the problem

Comment: I have edit my anser try the late answer, i don't know it would help or not. Just guess. Another thing, Do you really need to use Relative layout?

Comment: hi i have edited my listitem.xml file..but even then it is not working..plz help me

Comment: Then, i'm not sure i could help u.. anyway If you think i can help and your code is not secret.. you can email me.. i would take a look then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `layout:weight` property in your XML layout, there you can set desired layout weights for your header & listview. Then the listview and header width will adjust accordinly.
[check this for more info](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

Comment: hi thanks for the response...can u give me an example for my code here...thanks in advance